# Problem to initialize 2D Array in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have problems to initialize the "categorizedProductsPath" array, both approaches do not work, where´s the failure?

```
      // let categorizedProductsPath: number[][] = [];
      let categorizedProductsPath = new Array<number[]>(categorizedProducts.length);
      for (let k = 0; k < categorizedProducts.length; k++) {
        const categorizedProduct = categorizedProducts[k];
        const categoryOfCategorizedProduct = await this.getCategoryToProduct(+categorizedProduct.google_product_category);

        let currentParentId = categoryOfCategorizedProduct.parentId;
        while (currentParentId !== 0) {
          const parentCategory = await this.getCategoryToProduct(currentParentId);
          currentParentId = parentCategory.id;
          categorizedProductsPath[categorizedProduct.id].push(parentCategory.id); //***
        }
      }
```

The error (TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')) comes here ***:

```
categorizedProductsPath[categorizedProduct.id].push(parentCategory.id);
```

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created the outer array, but did not create the inner array.  You have to do `categorizedProductsPath[categorizedProduct.id] = []` first before you can `push` to it;

Note that this may create a sparse array if `categorizedProduct.id` are not consecutive integers starting from zero. It's still ok. But in case the order of `categorizedProduct.id` has no meaning, you may consider just using an object instead of an array.

Answer (score 1):

You want `categorizedProductsPath` to be a nested array of `number[][]`. But currently it is an empty array, you didn’t initialize it correctly.

`const arr = new Array(3)` will just give you an array of three `undefined`. If you want an array of three other empty arrays, like `[[], [], []]`, this is what you gonna do:

```js
const arr = new Array(3).fill(0).map(() => [])
```